# Porting a C Winforms project to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have written a smallish app for the company I currently work for in C# winforms.  I really want to deevlop some WPF skills, so I am going to attempt to port what I have written over to WPF.

My code relies on a number of dll#s written in VB.net and C++(marshalled), will WPF still support this?  The VB.net code returns treeviews and datasets, are these still valid in WPF?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be just fine. WPF and WinForms are just for presentation. The rest of your code will all be the same. However, your code for presenting these treeviews and datasets to the user will probably have to change.

Comment: aah okay.  So if  my program has an assembly that deals with just the presentation and then implements mainly a plugin architecture, I could get away with redesigning just the main assembly and still then plugin the dll's?

Comment: If your VB.net dlls rely on WinForms components and code, for example they create or handle `Control` objects (or anything else in the System.Windows.Forms namespace), then they will have to change. Your marshalled C++ dlls will remain as they are.